# Возможно ли использовать выражение "извини(те), что ..." + местоимение во 2-м л. ед. ч. ("ты", "Вы")

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, согласование, обращение

На одном из своих стримов блогер Ozon671games, после того, как другой блогер, VJlink, разбил его телевизор, сказал ему следующую фразу: "VJlink, извини, что ты сломал мне мой телевизор".

Разумеется, в данном случае это было довольно-таки косноязычно, но меня заинтересовал вопрос: а можно ли использовать ту же конструкцию ("извини, что ты ...", т.е. с местоимением во 2-м л. ед.ч.) с другими глаголами, чтобы это звучало корректно? Есть такие случаи употребления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Безусловно, в большинстве случаев такая формулировка имеет подтекст сарказма.

Но её также можно использовать и вполне искренне:

`Извини, что ты не успел на этот автобус.`

`Извини, что ты был вынужден через это пройти.` (тут я немного лукавлю: всё же это страдательный залог)

`Извини, что ты сюда впустую приехал.`

`Извини, что ты простыл пока ждал меня под дождем.`

И тому подобное.